# passthru background process sudo multiple commands

Tags: linux, bash, php, sudo

Have problem running the command in background. Below is configuration of code.

1] Using php `passthru` running a command as a different user than current

2] The command has multiple commands to run using different user than current

3] The following is php code run by user `dma22`.

```php
$webuser='dm22';
$webroot='/dm22';
/* basic command to run */
$theCommand=sprintf('sudo -u %s php -c ./php.ini %s/mycmd.php $message<$msgFile', $webuser,$webroot,$message,$msgFile);
/* log the errors */
$theCommand .= sprintf(' | sudo -u %s tee -a %s', $webroot, $logFilePath); //
/* run the above commands in background */
$theCommand .= ' & '; 

\passthru($theCommand);
echo "DONE";
```

4] PROBLEM: The above command runs but it waits to finish itself before doing echo. (Not running as background process)

5] Below is the $theCommand output which run on terminal as background process, but not running from php passthru as background process

```bash
sudo -u dm22 php -c ./php.ini /dm22/mycmd.php msg2024</dm22/msg2024.raw | sudo -u dm22 tee -1 /dm22/logs/msg2024.raw.log &
```

Any help will be appreciated...!!!

Comment: Is the PHP code running as `sudo -u dm22`?

Comment: php code is running as dma22 user.

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting output stream of `tee` command to `/dev/null` made the command to run in background.

The new command looks as following

```bash
sudo -u dm22 php -c ./php.ini /dm22/mycmd.php msg2024</dm22/msg2024.raw | sudo -u dm22 tee -1 /dm22/logs/msg2024.raw.log >/dev/null &
```